# Linux: How to extract frames from a video? (lossless)

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, framerate

I've read a few answers and articles on using programs like `VLC`, `MPlayer`, `ffmpeg`, etc., but none of the methods I've seen are "lossless." They don't capture every single frame. I want to extract each frame from a video as an image (100% quality, I don't want to lose any detail), so one could theoretically take those images and re-create the video file without being able to tell the difference from the original (excluding the lack of audio, of course).

Bonus points if I can specify a start and end time to grab frames from, so I don't have to crop the video file beforehand.

Comment: In order to possibly answer this some info about your `ffmpeg` version and the input file is required. Please show the complete console output of `ffmpeg -i input`.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185877/how-to-extract-images-from-video-file

Answer (score 34):

You can extract the frames as PNG, a lossless picture compression format. For example, to extract frames from the 5min mark to the 10min mark :

```
ffmpeg -ss 05:00 -i <input> -t 05:00 filename%05d.png
```

Comment: I get the error Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)

Comment: `ffmpeg` outputs `PNG8` files, which are *not* lossless, it's only 256 colors (same as GIF !! Only `PNG24` are lossless. `.bmp` would be a lossless option for `ffmpeg`

Comment: would you mind clarifying what `%05d` is? I see other use `%00d` ? Thanks!

Comment: %05d is correct. It means number the files and use a 5 digit zero-padded naming convention.

Answer (score 15):

There are several tools that should be able to extract all frames from a movie file:

**avconv**
`avconv -i file.avi -f image2 Out%00d.jpg`

**ffmpeg**
`ffmpeg -i input.file thumb%04d.png -hide_banner`

This can also export BMP, which take much less processing time than PNG or JPG.

There is also a bash script called [mov2frame.sh](https://gist.github.com/lvl99/d1aaca4649cd6c5f9daa92918121b4a6) that tries to automate the FFMPEG extraction process.

**Mplayer**
`mplayer -ao null -vo png input.file`

or another option:

`mplayer -nosound -vo png:z=9 my_file.mp4`

**VLC**
This media player apparently can export image sets using its filters, but seems troublesome unless it's your only usage or you have a portable version.

> 1. Create a folder to store your frames and copy the path to it. For Mac OSX/Linux users, this must be the full path (no ~).
> 2. Click Tools / Preferences in VLC.
> 3. Under “show settings”, click “all”.
> 4. Under “Video”, select “Filters”. Tick “Scene video filter”.
> 5. Expand “Filters” and select “Scene filter”,
> 6. Paste the path from earlier into “directory path prefix”.
> 7. Choose the fraction of frames to encode in the “recording ratio” box. 1/12 with output every 12, 1/1 will export them all
> 8. Click “save”.
> 9. Click Media / Open Video and find your video. Patiently let the whole thing play.
> 10. Click Tools / Preferences. Under “show settings”, click “all”. Under “video”, select “filters”. Uncheck “Scene video filter”. Click “save”. This is so that VLC won’t generate thumbnails the next time you play a video. link

There also appears to be some potential trouble with admin permissions on first program run:

> `sudo vlc
>   [sudo] password for mint16: 
>   VLC is not supposed to be run as root. Sorry.
>   If you need to use real-time priorities and/or privileged TCP ports
>   you can use vlc-wrapper (make sure it is Set-UID root and
>   cannot be run by non-trusted users first).`

VLC also performs much better when extracting to BMP instead of PNG

Comment: How can I reduce the framerate output using ffmpeg? Can I have for example only 2 images of frames per second?

Answer (score 2):

When doing this with ffmpeg, I have found that I often need to use the `-vsync 0` option (for example, when working with some VOB files from DVDs):

```
ffmpeg -i video.VOB -vsync 0 %06d.bmp
```

If you want to do a start and stop time too, it would look something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i video.VOB -vsync 0 -ss 01:30 -to 01:40 %06d.bmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code in opencv that worked for me to extract frames from video.

```
import cv2
import os

# Replace 'your_video_file.mp4' with the path to your video file
video_path = 'your_video_file.mp4'

# Create a VideoCapture object
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

# Check if the video file is opened successfully
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Error: Could not open video file.")
    exit()

# Create a directory to store the frames
output_directory = 'frames'
os.makedirs(output_directory, exist_ok=True)

# Loop to read frames from the video
frame_count = 0
while True:
    # Read a frame from the video
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Check if the frame is read successfully
    if not ret:
        print("End of video.")
        break

    # Save the frame as an image file
    frame_filename = os.path.join(output_directory, f'frame_{frame_count:04d}.png')
    cv2.imwrite(frame_filename, frame)

    frame_count += 1

# Release the VideoCapture object
cap.release()

print(f"{frame_count} frames saved in '{output_directory}'.")
```